# Iron Route to inserted value by user in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I need to run function that takes an input from user and routes to that value. For example inserted value is

```html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZiN_NqT-Us
```

And it should route to the url:

```html
download?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_ZiN_NqT-Us
```

I get the value and Set.session to get Session back in Router, the following way but it doesn't get any value.

```js
Template.inputBar.events({
 'click #download':function(event, template) {
  var url = template.find('.url').value;
  if (url.value != "") {
   Session.set('url', url);
  } 
  else {
   alert('paste link');
  }
 }
});
```

Routes to inserted value and executes call to server:

```js
Router.map(function(){
  this.route('frontPage', {path: '/'} );
  this.route('downloadLinks', {
   path: '/download?link=:url',
   data: function() {
          var url = Session.get('url');
          Meteor.call('command', url, function(error, result) {
          if(result.stdout) {
            console.log(result.stdout)
          }
          else {
            alert("Not supported site");
          }
        });
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs for Router.go](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#using-javascript)

```
Template.inputBar.events({
  'click #download':function(event, template) {
    var url = template.find('.url').value;
      if (url.value != "") {
        Router.go(url.value);
      } else {
        alert('paste link');
      }
    }
});
```

This will redirect to the route you want.